# Wordpress - echo the password fields only once

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, echo

having some trouble:

Basically, I have a page which displays custom posts, like blog posts. But I want the content to be private, and not be viewable until a password has been entered.

I have cracked the password bit and you have to enter the password to view the posts all fine. BUT... For each "resident-mainarea-wrap" post that there is on the page it echos a password field and submit button.. So if I have 3 posts on the page it echos outs the "get_the_password_form" 3 times. They all work, but it looks messy, I only want one to be displayed.

Basically I need to hide all the password fields that are echoed after the first one.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
<?php
if ( !post_password_required() ) : ?>

<img class="resident-image" src="<?php echo $image; ?>" />

    <div class="resident-mainarea-wrap">
        <div class="resident-mainarea">
            <div class="resident-date">
                <?php echo $date; ?>
            </div>
            <div class="resident-content">
                <?php echo $post_content; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<?php else: ?>

    <?php echo get_the_password_form(); ?> 

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: So that code snippet probably runs three times, it would probably be better to figure out why instead of adding hacks to avoid outputting the password for three times in the code

Comment: @adeno it runs 3 times because there is 3 posts. if there was 4 it would run 4 times. It runs for each post that is there. So there needs to be a bit of php that says only run once on the entire page.. but i'm not a developer so don't know php unfortunately..

Comment: For password protected posts, each post has unique password so it makes sense to display multiple forms, right?

Comment: @dharmang no the content is from repeater fields in this case so they are from the same post, in turn they all share the same password.

Comment: password could be same but WP don't understand that natively, it stores password for each post separately, what you need is either custom post type or group of posts kind of thing. check if such plugin is available.

Comment: Thats what I have.. I don't think i'm explaining it right, im just not sure how else to put it.